# PostgreSQL: Function not updating records when called in a nested select

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function updating records in my PostgreSQL 11 database (the goal is to change record ids and all foreign keys referencing it):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_nip(old_nip character varying, new_nip character varying)
  RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  nb_nips_found int;
BEGIN
  raise notice 'NIP to replace: %, New NIP: %', old_nip, new_nip;

  SELECT COUNT (nip) INTO nb_nips_found
    FROM data_infos_patient WHERE nip = new_nip;

  if nb_nips_found > 0 then
    raise notice 'New NIP already existing, not doing anything.';
  else
    raise notice 'NIP will be replaced.';

    -- temporary disable constraints till the end of the transaction  
    SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

    UPDATE data_prelevements SET PRV_NIP = new_nip WHERE PRV_NIP = old_nip;
    UPDATE data_infos_biologie SET NIP = new_nip WHERE NIP = old_nip;
    UPDATE data_chromosomes SET NIP = new_nip WHERE NIP = old_nip;
    -- ...
    -- A lot of other Updates ...
    -- ... 
    UPDATE data_infos_patient SET NIP = new_nip WHERE NIP = old_nip;

  end if;
  return nb_nips_found;
END;
$function$
;
```

When I call it for updating a single record, like this:

```sql
select replace_nip('123456789','987654321');
```

it works, I got 0 as result (exit code which means the replacement has been done), and the records are well updated.

But as I have a lot of records to update, I created a table containing a list of old and new ids:

```
Table tmp_nip_old_new:

|old_nip        |new_nip        |
|---------------|---------------|
| 0000000002    |9999999992     |
| 0000000003    |9999999993     |
| 0000000004    |9999999994     |
| 0000000005    |9999999995     |
```

And I call the function like this:

```sql
select old_nip, new_nip, replace_nip(old_nip,new_nip) as result from (
  select old_nip, new_nip
  from tmp_nip_old_new
) as tmp_nip;
```

I got the excepted result:

```
|old_nip        |new_nip        |result     |
|---------------|---------------|-----------|
| 0000000002    |9999999992     |0          |
| 0000000003    |9999999993     |0          |
| 0000000004    |9999999994     |0          |
| 0000000005    |9999999995     |0          |
```

BUT the records are NOT updated...

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the RAISE NOTICE message the expected number of times?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, I see the messages the expected number of times...

Comment: Is it possible that you aren't committing the changes?

Comment: @Jeremy No, I use Dbeaver and autocommit is set to true. I also tried with psql directly and the result is the same.

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened, I changed nothing (just shutdown and restart the postges instance), but this morning it's working as expected...